# Is the flow of an analytic vector field also analytic?

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, analytic-functions

Let $X$ be an analytic vector field on a smooth manifold. Is it true that the flow $\Phi_t:M\to M$ associated to that vector field is also analytic?

Comment: Cauchy - Kovalevskaya  theorem.

Comment: Thanks studiosus. This is exactly what I was looking for. Adding a verb could make this into a fully fletched answer ;)

Comment: So this begs the question whether this also holds for smooth vector fields? If $X$ is smooth, is $\Phi_t$ smooth? 

Apparently one can construct linear partial differential operators (Lewy's example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewy%27s_example) $L$, such that $L(u)=g(u)$ does not have a solution for smooth $g$. But these operators are chosen in a particular way and contain complex coefficients, so I wonder whether the plain time derivative does not belong to this degenerate class?

Comment: The flow equation is not a PDE, it is a (system of) ODE. It always has a unique solution, $C^k$ if the original vector field is $C^k$ etc.

Comment: I should also point out that "analytic vector field" does not (obviously) make sense on a smooth manifold. Change coordinate charts and an analytic function might no longer be analytic... you want an analytic structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested: First of all (as Mike correctly noted), to have a well-defined notion of a real-analytic vector field (or any real-analytic tensor) on the manifold $M$, you need not only a smooth manifold but a manifold equipped with a real analytic structure. Secondly, the equation $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_t(m)= X(m)$, $m\in M$, $X$ is a vector field on $M$, may not have a short term solution without further hypothesis. One way to guarantee existence of a short term solution is to assume compactness of $M$. Given this, Cauchy - Kovalevskaya theorem implies that the 1st order ODE $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_t(m)= X(m)$ has a real analytic solution on $M$ for $t\in [0,T]$ and some $T>0$ which will the required real analytic flow on $M$. (To apply the theorem, use it one chart at a time and then use uniqueness of solution to guarantee that the local solutions yield a global solution.)  Note that compactness of $M$ also implies existence of a **long term solution**, i.e. a solution (a flow) which exists (and is real-analytic) for all values of $t\ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks, studiosus. 

By long term solution do you mean a solution that exists for all $t\in\mathbb R$?